# Yii2 execution time (total time for serving the current request)

Tags: yii, yii2

What is the equivalent of method

```
Yii::getLogger()->getExecutionTime()
```

in Yii2, that present the total time for serving the current request?

Comment: I believe the getExecutionTime was a [yii1 thing](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLogger#executionTime-detail) ?

Comment: Yes, he needs equivalent for Yii 2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should simply use :

```
Yii::getLogger()->getElapsedTime();
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-log-logger.html#getElapsedTime()-detail